# How to disconnect from docker and the server, and keep the script running in the background

Tags: python, docker

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import torch
from torch_geometric.datasets import TUDataset
from torch_geometric.data import Data, Dataset,DataLoader

dataset = TUDataset(root='data/TUDataset', name='MUTAG')

print()
print(f'Dataset: {dataset}:')
print('====================')
print(f'Number of graphs: {len(dataset)}')
print(f'Number of features: {dataset.num_features}')
print(f'Number of classes: {dataset.num_classes}')

data = dataset[0]  # Get the first graph object.

print()
print(data)
print('=============================================================')

# Gather some statistics about the first graph.
print(f'Number of nodes: {data.num_nodes}')
print(f'Number of edges: {data.num_edges}')
print(f'Average node degree: {data.num_edges / data.num_nodes:.2f}')
#print(f'Has isolated nodes: {data.has_isolated_nodes()}')
#print(f'Has self-loops: {data.has_self_loops()}')
#print(f'Is undirected: {data.is_undirected()}')

torch.manual_seed(12345)
dataset = dataset.shuffle()

train_dataset = dataset[:150]
test_dataset = dataset[150:]

print(f'Number of training graphs: {len(train_dataset)}')
print(f'Number of test graphs: {len(test_dataset)}')



train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=False)

for step, data in enumerate(train_loader):
    print(f'Step {step + 1}:')
    print('=======')
    print(f'Number of graphs in the current batch: {data.num_graphs}')
    print(data)
    print()


from torch.nn import Linear
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv
from torch_geometric.nn import global_mean_pool


class GCN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_channels):
        super(GCN, self).__init__()
        torch.manual_seed(12345)
        self.conv1 = GCNConv(dataset.num_node_features, hidden_channels)
        self.conv2 = GCNConv(hidden_channels, hidden_channels)
        self.conv3 = GCNConv(hidden_channels, hidden_channels)
        self.lin = Linear(hidden_channels, dataset.num_classes)

    def forward(self, x, edge_index, batch):
        # 1. Obtain node embeddings 
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
        x = x.relu()
        x = self.conv2(x, edge_index)
        x = x.relu()
        x = self.conv3(x, edge_index)

        # 2. Readout layer
        x = global_mean_pool(x, batch)  # [batch_size, hidden_channels]

        # 3. Apply a final classifier
        x = F.dropout(x, p=0.5, training=self.training)
        x = self.lin(x)
        
        return x


model = GCN(hidden_channels=64)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

def train():
    model.train()

    for data in train_loader:  # Iterate in batches over the training dataset.
         out = model(data.x, data.edge_index, data.batch)  # Perform a single forward pass.
         loss = criterion(out, data.y)  # Compute the loss.
         loss.backward()  # Derive gradients.
         optimizer.step()  # Update parameters based on gradients.
         optimizer.zero_grad()  # Clear gradients.

def test(loader):
     model.eval()

     correct = 0
     for data in loader:  # Iterate in batches over the training/test dataset.
         out = model(data.x, data.edge_index, data.batch)  
         pred = out.argmax(dim=1)  # Use the class with highest probability.
         correct += int((pred == data.y).sum())  # Check against ground-truth labels.
     return correct / len(loader.dataset)  # Derive ratio of correct predictions.


for epoch in range(1, 10000):
    train()
    train_acc = test(train_loader)
    test_acc = test(test_loader)
    print(f'Epoch: {epoch:03d}, Train Acc: {train_acc:.4f}, Test Acc: {test_acc:.4f}')
```

It runs in a docker container on a linux server without error.

I want to be able to run this code in the background, so that I can be disconnected from the linux server that docker is running on (e.g. the internet connection to the server goes down), and when I log back in, the script is still running.

To achieve this on a command line without docker, I would usually log in to the server, and run:

`python script.py &` , and then log out and back in, and the script will be still running.

How do I achieve this with docker? When I run the above script with `python script.py &`, the printing progress to screen means I cannot get a command line in docker (because the printing is happeneing too quickly), to be able to log out and log back in.

I don't want to just 'not print anything to screen' because I want to see the progress printing at the start.

So is there another way to set a script running in docker, so I can be disconnected from docker and the underlying server, and log back in and the docker container and script is still running?

Comment: Where are you running `python script.py &`? In a shell in a container?

Comment: yes, I want to run the script in a docker container, in a linux shell.

Comment: (and sorry, yes, that's what I'm doing at the minute e.g. with the script above, but i can't get the command line back to logout and log back in because of the printing).

Comment: You can run 2 commands. One will be the `docker` with `-d` flag, and after that `docker logs --follow containerName`. No need to use `&`.

Comment: thanks do you mean run two commands consecutively? i usually start the docker container with ```docker exec -it containerName /bin/bash``` ; so you do mean do (1) ```docker exec -dit containerName /bin/bash``` and then (2) ```docker logs --follow containerName``` and then (3) ```python script.py```